# sub-setting rows based on dates in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to solve a problem in R. I have 2 data frames which look like this:

```
df1 <- 
  Date    Rainfall_Duration 
6/14/2016       10 
6/15/2016       20 
6/17/2016       10 
8/16/2016       30 
8/19/2016       40 

df2 <- 
  Date    Removal.Rate 
6/17/2016    64.7 
6/30/2016    22.63 
7/14/2016    18.18 
8/19/2016    27.87
```

I want to look up the dates from df2 in df1 and their corresponding Rainfall_Duration data. For example, I want to look for the 1st date of df2 in df1 and subset rows in df1 for that specific date and 7 days prior to that. additionally, for example: for 6/30/2016 (in df2) there is no dates available in df1 within it's 7 days range. So, in this case I just want to extract the results same as it's previous date (6/17/2016) in df2. Same logic goes for 7/14/2016(df2). 
The output should look like this:

```
df3<- 
Rate.Removal.Date    Date       Rainfall_Duration 
6/17/2016                6/14/2016               10 
6/17/2016                6/15/2016               20 
6/17/2016                6/17/2016               10 
6/30/2016                6/14/2016               10 
6/30/2016                6/15/2016               20 
6/30/2016                6/17/2016               10 
7/14/2016                6/14/2016               10 
7/14/2016                6/15/2016               20 
7/14/2016                6/17/2016               10 
8/19/2016                8/16/2016               30 
8/19/2016                8/19/2016               40
```

I could subset data for the 7 days range. But could not do it when no dates are available in that range. I have the following code:

```
library(plyr) 
library (dplyr) 
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y") 
df2$Date <- as.Date(df2$Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y") 

df3 <- lapply(df2$Date, function(x){ 
  filter(df1, between(Date, x-7, x)) 
})   

names(df3) <- as.character(df2$Date) 
bind_rows(df3, .id = "Rate.Removal.Date") 
df3 <- ldply (df3, data.frame, .id = "Rate.Removal.Date")
```

I hope I could explain my problem properly. I would highly appreciate if someone can help me out with this code or a new one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by explicitly generating all of the dates on which you want to collect the rainfall duration then binding.

To that end, I `split` each row and generated a `rainfallDate` column for each that included the seven previous days. Then, I bound the rows back together and used `left_join` to get the rainfall data. Finally, I filter out the rows with missing rainfall information

```
df2 %>%
  split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
  lapply(function(x){
    data.frame(
      x
      , rainfallDate = seq(x$Date - 7, x$Date, 1)
    )
  }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c(rainfallDate = "Date")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Rainfall_Duration))
```

gives

```
        Date Removal.Rate rainfallDate Rainfall_Duration
1 2016-06-17        64.70   2016-06-14                10
2 2016-06-17        64.70   2016-06-15                20
3 2016-06-17        64.70   2016-06-17                10
4 2016-08-19        27.87   2016-08-16                30
5 2016-08-19        27.87   2016-08-19                40
```

Note that if the dates without rainfall information are actually 0's, you could skip the filter line and use `replace_na` from `tidyr` to set them to explicit zeros (e.g., if you want average rainfall or to include the removal dates without any days of rainfall ahead of them).

An alternative is possible if you are actually interested in a summary value for each date (e.g., total rain in the past seven days). First, I would generate a rainfall dataset that actually had entries for every day of observation. For that, I used `complete` from `tidyr` to add an explicit zero entry for each day then used `rollapply` from `zoo` to calculate the sum in the rolling previous seven days.

```
completeRainfall <-
  df1 %>%
  complete(Date = full_seq(c(as.Date("2016-06-10"), max(Date)), 1)
           , fill = list(Rainfall_Duration = 0)) %>%
  mutate(prevSeven = rollapply(Rainfall_Duration, 7, sum
                               , fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

Then, a simple join will give you both that day's rainfall and the summarized total from the past seven days. This is particularly useful if your `Date`s for `df1` are ever within seven days of each other to avoid copying the same rows multiple times.

```
left_join(
  df2
  , completeRainfall
)
```

Gives

```
        Date Removal.Rate Rainfall_Duration prevSeven
1 2016-06-17        64.70                10        40
2 2016-06-30        22.63                 0         0
3 2016-07-14        18.18                 0         0
4 2016-08-19        27.87                40        70
```